# Webpack Usage of chunkFilename

Tags: node.js, webpack

Iam having trouble understand the use of chunkFilename property. Where do we need it?

I cant find any usage in webpack docs.

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry:['./util.js','./index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude:/node_modules/ }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chunkFilename` is used for naming chunks :]

Chunks are created using `dynamic` import such as `import('./file')` or webpacks `require.ensure()` syntax.